# RunspacePool behavior

Tags: multithreading, powershell

Given the code here, which is an adaptation of [this example](https://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/02/11/multithreading-powershell-scripts/) modified for my coding standards and to use a function rather than a script block, my understanding is that
The ForEach loop runs 20 times, spawning 20 jobs.
The DoWhile loop waits for the jobs to complete, which is dependent on the random number for sleep time of each job.
Once all jobs are complete that is written to the console.
Then the results are extracted from each job and written to a Grid View.

All this makes sense, but when I run it, it takes no more than half a second (always 1 extra period only) before 'All jobs completed", then it takes a rather long time before the Grid View shows up. But, it seems to me that it should take a while for all the jobs to complete (waiting for the Sleep to complete for each), and then the grid view should be populated almost instantly.
So, what is wrong with my understanding, since it is the reverse of reality?

```
function Sleep-Time {
   Param (
      [int]$runNumber
   )
   $sleepTime = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 10
   Start-Sleep -Seconds $sleepTime
   $runResult = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      runNumber = $runNumber
      sleep = $sleepTime
   }

$runResult
}

$sleepFunction = (Get-Command Sleep-Time).scriptBlock
$throttle = 5
$runspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $throttle)
$runspacePool.Open()
$jobs = @()

ForEach ($i in 1..20) {
   $job = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($sleepFunction).AddArgument($i)
   $job.RunspacePool = $runspacePool
   $jobs += @{
      runNum = $i
      pipe = $job
      result = $job.BeginInvoke()
   }
}

Write-Host "Waiting.." -noNewline
Do {
   Write-Host "." -noNewline
   Start-Sleep -seconds .25
} While ( $jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false)
Write-Host "All jobs completed!"

$results = @()
ForEach ($job in $jobs) {
    $results += $job.Pipe.EndInvoke($job.result)
}

$results | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Add some write-verbose or write-host statements so you can see where you are at each stage and how long they are taking.

Comment: That's what I thought I had. "All jobs completed" ethos once Jobs.Result.IsCompleted no longer contains false, meaning I don't see that until all the jobs are done.
And, I can't see a way to add a Write-Host to the Sleep-Time function, because it's running as a job. So, where are you thinking would be useful to put an additional Write-Host?

Comment: Sorry hasn't noticed those. It is a puzzler, hopefully someone else will have a suggestion.

Comment: Haven't tested, but I suspect this line is causing the immediate exit: While ( $jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false).  Seems like that should be -notcontains.

Comment: @mjolinor is correct on the problem line. Check the comments of the linked post. The author posted this fix there: `While (@(Get-Job -State “Running”).count -gt 0)
{ Write-Debug “All threads submitted, waiting for them to finish…”
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000
}`